# Hub method doesn't work from outside the hub class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Here is the controller method, that receives `userName` that should be kicked.

```
   public ActionResult Kick(string userName)
    {
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();            
        var user = userService.GetUserByName(userName);
        hub.Clients.Client(user.ConnectionIdInHub).kickUser();
        return Json(new { success = true});
    }
```

`kickUser()` - it's a JS method. But when the `kickUser()` is being executed from controller method `Kick()` nothing happened on the client side.

```
 chatHub.client.kickUser = function () {
        window.location.replace(window.kickUserActionUrl);
    }
```

What am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

**I tried to do this:**

```
public static void OnKicked(string connectionId)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).closeConnection();
        }
```

I call hub method like this            `ChatHub.OnKicked(user.ConnectionIdInHub);` 
but it still doesn't work

**Here's the another way to solution:**

I'm calling on the client side `setInterval()` method, that sends to server request every ten secs. JSon method by receiving this request on the server is checking one thing: is the current user `IsKicked=true`, in that case JSon will send back `new {success=true}` and there user will be reconnected on the Kick Page.

Comment: What SignalR scripts have you included on the client side? Just want to verify that you're including the generated proxy and necessary supporting scripts.

Comment: @RobReagan
You mean this? `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
`

Comment: That's exactly the right ones. Thanks.

Comment: @RobReagan
So..what do you think? What's the reason the hub method isn't calling from controller?

Comment: Can you add the code that shows how you're setting up your chatHub on the client? Also, how are you setting the value of user.ConnectionIdInHub in your first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to execute a hub methods from outside the hub class. You can call the hub method right from the client side like this:

```
var myHub = $.coonection.hubName;
myHub.server.myMethod; //name of the method should begin with a small letter
```